# What are the French equivalents of “germophobia”, “germophobic”, and “a germophobe”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, genre

What are the French equivalents of

1. germophobia
2. germophobic
3. a germophobe

and what are their genders?

Is it

(1) la germophobie (2) germophobe (3) un/e germophobe

**or is it**

(1) la mysophobie (2) mysophobe (3) un/e mysophobe

**or is it both** ?

Comment: Les deux sont équivalents d'après https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysophobie dans le résultat : la peur des germes nocifs ou de la saleté (connotée *impure* par rapport à son idéal) qui les contient.

Comment: @Personne Thank you for your help.  I’ve failed to find the french words **germophobe**, **un/e germophobe**, **mysophobe** and **un/e mysophobie** in the Wikipedia article. Are these 4 words actual French words?

Comment: They are used by specialists (Airport English :-)

Comment: @Personne Thank you for replying. :) What’s Airport English? But more importantly if I say the words **germophobe**, **un/e germophobe**, **mysophobe** and **un/e mysophobe** then will people in France understand me? Are these 4 words used by french speakers? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Une langue d'aéroport est une connaissance basique d'une langue qui n'est pas votre langue maternelle, elle vous permet de survivre en terre étrangère. — Avec des personnes liées au monde médicale ou psy ces mots devraient passer, sinon vous devez donner leur signification (pour *m**y**so* que l'ont rattachera par réflexe auditif à *m**i**sogyne* et *germo* qui est lié à [cousin ]germain) par respect votre interlocuteur qui ne connait pas forcément le sens des mots : « Il/elle est mysophobe, *myso* avec un *y*, il a peur de la saleté, des choses impures. »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mysophobe/mysophobie* wouldn't be understood at all by most if not all people in France.

*Germophobe/germophobie* would be better, but I guess some people would think these words are related to Germany.

A couple of words sometimes used, especially this year, are *virusophobe* and to a lesser extent *virusophobie*. They are more specialized than the former but immediately understood by everyone, although probably not considered as official, "serious" words. Otherwise, you can just say *quelqu'un qui a la phobie des microbes*.

Comment: I think the term "nareux" could also somehow apply here.

Comment: @LaurentS. It does indeed but is only known in Eastern France and Belgium. https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/grand-est/marne/coronavirus-etre-nareux-mot-local-qui-entre-dictionnaire-1876372.html

Comment: Merci beaucoup @jlliagre for your help!!!  So just to confirm, (1) “germophobia” = « la germophobie » or better still « la virusphobie », (2) “germophobic” = « germophobe » or better still « virusphobe » and (3) “a germophobe” = « un/e germophobe » or better still « un/e virusphobe ». Is this all correct?

Comment: That's it ! ---

Comment: Thank you @jlliagre very much and happy holidays!!! 